# Is the Azure SQL Reporting Service a complete replacement of SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-reporting

I think the question in this thread's title is self-explanatory. Is there still a way to use SSRS or is SQL Azure Reporting Service the way to go?
This question may sound a little bit strange but I even have never used SSRS (seems to be server sided), just have to know this for a proof-of-concept paper.

Thanks :)

Comment: [SQL Reporting will discontinue service on October 31, 2014.](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-reporting/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [comparison of SQL Azure Reporting and SSRS](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/features/reporting/) by Microsoft.

Comment: To highlight the differences from that link: Azure Reporting can only connect to Azure DBs, versus SSRS connecting to a variety of DBs, and Azure Reporting doesn't offer Subscriptions or scheduled delivery. These differences will rule out Azure Reporting for many.

Comment: Thanks so far. But Azure Reporting runs on Azure directly whereas SSRS only can run outside of Azure and use SQL Azure as data source, right?

Comment: Azure SSRS runs in azure can only use Azure data sources, SSRS could in theory run in azure. (But lets say no for now since I don't know of anyone who has tried to make that happen and can use Azure data sources) Here is a link to the data sources SSRS supports http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159219.aspx

Comment: Thanks, do you know whether the Azure Report Service is still for free at the moment? Want to avoid to pay without knowing it

Comment: Down voted because the link gives a 404 - Page Not Found error.